# knockout bindings not being applied in rails 3 remote partial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, knockout.js

I have this view model in a js file that loads with my app:

```
var portfolioViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.selectedCompany = ko.observable('All Companies');
    this.allComp = ko.observable(true);
    this.chartSeries = ko.observableArray();
    $(function(){
        self.chart.addSeries(companyChart['All Companies']);
    });
    $.each(companyData, function(index, company) {
       self[company] = ko.observable(false);
       self.chartSeries.push(companyChart[company]);
   });


    this.chart = ko.observable();

    this.showCompany = function(company){
        self.hideCompanies();
        self[company](true);
        self.allComp(false);
        self.selectedCompany(company);
        while(self.chart.series.length > 0){
            self.chart.series[0].remove(true);
        }
        self.chart.addSeries(companyChart[company]);
    }
    this.allCompanies = function(){
        self.hideCompanies();
        self.allComp(true);
        self.selectedCompany('All Companies');
        self.chart.addSeries(companyChart['All Companies']);
        $.each(companyData, function(index, company) {
            self.chart.addSeries(companyChart[company]);
        });
    }

    this.hideCompanies = function(){
        $.each(companyData, function(i, c){
           self[c](false);
        });
        while(self.chart.series.length > 0){
            self.chart.series[0].remove(true);
        }
    }
}
```

It controls adding series to a high charts chart, based on whichever company is selected.

In my partial, I have the some HTML, and then the following javascript code block:

```
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    <% companies = current_user.list_of_companies %>
    <% funding_date = current_user.first_funding_date * 1000 %>
    var companyData = <%= companies.map(&:name).to_json.html_safe %>;
    var companyChart = {};

    companyChart['All Companies'] = {
                           name: 'Total Portfolio',
                           pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
                           pointStart: <%=funding_date %>,
                           data: <%= current_user.portfolio_values.group("portfolio_values.day").select("portfolio_values.day, SUM(portfolio_values.value) as totals").map(&:totals).collect{|x| x.to_i} %>
                         }

    <% companies.each do |company|%>

    companyChart['<%= company.name %>'] = {
                          name: '<%= company.name %>',
                          pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
                          pointStart: <%= funding_date %>,
                          data: <%= current_user.portfolio_values.where(:company_id => company.id).map(&:value).collect{|x| x.to_i} %>
                        }

    <% end %>

    var vm = new portfolioViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);


    vm.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
          chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart1',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                zoomType: 'xy',
                type: 'areaspline',
                style: {
                    color: '#ffffff'
                }
             },
            labels : {
                style: {
                    color: 'red'
                }
            },
            colors: [
            '#ea00ff',
            '#229aff',
            '#ff4e00',
            '#ea00ff',
            '#229aff',
            '#ff4e00',
            '#ea00ff',
            '#229aff',
            '#ff4e00',
            '#ea00ff',
            '#229aff',
            '#ff4e00'
            ],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                enabled: false,
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
                }, {
                    type: 'ytd',
                    text: 'YTD'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                            fill: 'none',
                            stroke: 'none',
                            style: {
                                color: '#fff',
                                fontWeight: 'bold'
                            },
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    stroke: 'none',
                                    fill: 'black'
                                },
                                select: {
                                    stroke: 'none',
                                    fill: 'black',
                                    style: {
                                        color: 'white'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        inputStyle: {
                            color: '#fff',
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            borderColor:'transparent',
                            background: 'transparent'

                        },
                        labelStyle: {
                            color: 'silver',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
            },
            navigator: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            plotOptions : {
                areaspline : {
                    lineWidth : 2,
                    fillOpacity : .2,
                    shadow:true,
                    marker : {
                        enabled : false,
                        symbol: 'circle'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
              alternateGridColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
              gridLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
              lineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
              lineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                gridLineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
                type: 'datetime',
                lineColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            },
            scrollbar : {
                enabled : false
            },
        series: vm.chartSeries()
      });

</script>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
```

Sometimes the bindings are applied and the scripts load with the partial, but many times they do not. When they do not load with the remote call to the partial (even though the HTML comes through) the script block will be completely missing it seems.

I'm not even sure how to start debugging this. Does anyone see any obvious mistakes? I'm very new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if there's a javascript error of any kind that stops the execution of later javascript, that will prevent your ko model from loading, or cause it to load only part way. I recommend using Firebug with Firefox, or something similar, to check for the javascript error causing the problem.

Also, the 'gon' gem is a good way to get information from your rails model into your javascript. I also like using the rabl gem with .json.rabl templates for ajax requests to update the knockout model.